# Weird Behaviour of MySQL stored procedure

Tags: c#, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in mysql as defined below

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS subway.cust_inventory;
CREATE PROCEDURE subway.`cust_inventory`(IN lastItem INT,IN lastValue INT)
BEGIN
delete from temp_inventory;
drop table   temp_inventory;
create table  temp_inventory as
SELECT CONCAT ('390',
    cast(DATE (t6.InventoryDate) as char)
    ,cast(t6.SKUorItem as char)
    ) AS PK,t6.CustomerID, t6.entityID, t6.inventoryDate, t6.SKUorItem,      t6.Category, t6.inventory FROM
(
SELECT
'3' as CustomerID,
'90' as entityID,
t1.InventoryDate as inventoryDate, 
t1.idItem as SKUorItem,
t3.categoryInventary as Category,
@lastValue :=  if( @lastItem = t1.idItem, @lastValue + ifnull(t1.buyQty,0),    ifnull(t1.buyQty,0) ) as inventory,
@lastItem := t1.idItem
FROM
(
select InventoryDate, idItem, ifnull(sum(buyqty),0) as buyqty FROM(
(SELECT date(date) as InventoryDate, idItem, ifnull(Sum(movedQuantity),0) as buyqty
FROM subway.StockMovement
GROUP BY idItem, date(date)
)
UNION
(SELECT date(date) as InventoryDate, idItem,  ifnull(Sum(initialBuyQuantity),0) as buyqty
FROM subway.InvoiceStock where type = 'buy'  GROUP BY idItem, date(date))

UNION
 (select date(date) as inventorydate, idItem,ifnull(-sum(quantity),0) as  buyQty 
from subway.saleitem
group by idItem, date(date)
)
) t5
group by inventorydate,idItem
) t1
LEFT JOIN subway.item as t2 ON t1.iditem = t2.iditem
LEFT JOIN subway.CategoryInventary as t3 on t2.idCategoryInventary =    t3.idCategoryInventary
order by t1.iditem, t1.InventoryDate
) t6 where t6.inventorydate = '2015-06-09' order by inventoryDate,SKUorItem
;
END;
```

This procedure inserts 72 records in temp_inventory table
This works well when i call the procedure from command prompt or from toad for mysql

But when i call the same procedure from C# code as specified below

```
mySQLConn.GetConnection();
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("cust_inventory", mySQLConn.Conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("lastItem", 0));
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("lastValue", 0));
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Dispose();
            MySqlDataReader myreader = new MySqlCommand("Select * from temp_inventory",mySQLConn.Conn).ExecuteReader();
```

This give wrong values in the column inventory (Last column)

Any idea why this is happening

Comment: Just two questions: Why don't you let the stored procedure return the results instead of issuing 2 calls from the C# application? What happens if the stored procedure is called from another instance of the application while the first instance tries to read from `temp_inventory`?

Comment: I was using the same approach as u are suggesting, but after many attempts, it was working fine on commandline but not from c#, thats y i introduced temp table, will undo and switch back

Comment: Well, I'd have tried to fix that instead of your current approach - this is bound to cause trouble.

Comment: Instead of parameters and declaring variables and initializing them to 0, SET @lastValue=0, @lastItem=0; works, dont know whats the difference betwwen `DECLARE lastValue int default 0; and set @lastValue=0; In c# only the latter work and in command line both working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following code. 0 is treated in different manner in MySql while passing as parameter value.

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("lastItem",MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=0);
cmd.Parameters.Add(new MySqlParameter("lastValue", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value=0);
```

No need to external call   `cmd.Dispose();` `.Net` Clr will take care of this internally.

You are just passing 0 value to these parameters so, just create two variable inside stored procedure and set value to 0. No need to create any parameter in storedprocedure, so there will be no need to pass them from `c#` code.

```
SET @lastValue=0, @lastItem=0;
```